# Machine Learning Classification with MNIST DATA FORMAT?

Tags: python, keras, mnist

I"m a newbie in machine learning, but till now stackoverflow community helped me a lot to understand a lot of things related to programming. My question is:
Is it important to convert your image dataset in Mnist Data Format? I have huge image dataset (.jpg format) with labels. I recently saw Keras Fashion Mnist and thought of asking this question. So your answers about this will help me alot... 
If there is anything unclear please feel free to ask me so I can explain more. 
Thank you :)

Comment: If you are just learning how to use Keras, it may be better to convert your datasets in MNIST format so that you can follow some of the tutorials. However, it is not necessary. There are many ways, you are package your files and labels in a set of HDF5 files, or you can use `flow_from_directory()` method of Keras, use Tensorflow dataset format etc. There are many such ways.

Comment: Thank you @Parag. The thing I wanna know is if I package my image dataset and labels together in HDF5 file system will it be easier to apply CNN on them for classification?

Comment: Once you learn the different methods, you will be comfortable with each of them. For me, the solution using TF dataset class is the best. However, [`flow_from_directory`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) is the simplest.